# Subsequent duplicate close votes should automatically upvote the possible duplicate comment

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

When voting to close as a duplicate, an automatic comment is generated, that's good.

But sometimes that comment is lost in the influx of other comments, not visible to viewers or sometimes the OP (even though that one was improved by the banner OP is seeing when his post has pending votes).

My suggestion is simple, just as subsequent custom off-topic close votes upvote the original automatic comments, so should subsequent duplicate votes on the same question.

Comment: What about multi dups?

Comment: @MichaelT: Each automatic upvote goes to the corresponding suggested duplicate. Just like with custom off-topic reasons.

Comment: So a question duped to two questions... Casts two votes?  And what if they are dups themselves? What happens if the dups are reversed later?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the closed questions themselves. Only with the comments generated by the vote.

Comment: **+1** I'd been meaning to request this for a while.

Answer (score 7):

This has been implemented; close-as-duplicate votes should now upvote matching comments if they exist.