# Auto-upvote comment during Low Quality review when selecting same reason

Tags: feature-request, comments, review, low-quality-posts

While working with the Low Quality review queue, when selecting a reason why you believe a post should be deleted, you automatically comment on the post with a canned piece of text explaining why you voted one way or another (if it doesn't already exist from another reviewer).

When you select the same reason as another reviewer and the comment already exists, what would we think about having it auto-upvote that comment instead of just doing nothing?

[image: preview]

In the example above, another user had chosen to flag the answer for deletion for the same reason I picked, so I would expect my action to upvote their comment.

Comment: This is a very reasonable request - why hasn't it got *any* response, I wonder..

Comment: +1 was just writing this request out when it popped up in the "someone beat you to it" list of questions :)

Comment: This is [status-completed for duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218295/282094). I found this question while searching for duplicates. It shouldn't be difficult to add the auto-upvoter for each reason; it won't post the subsequent person's comment (nor upvote the existing one), it just silently eats them.

Answer (score 4):

It might be argued it's not worth the dev time and site resources to do this given it's only a comment upvote and especially as the comment disappears when the review is completed.

### *Possibly* not much resources

When you cast your vote in the review queue, the site already checks if there is already a *matching* comment (it doesn't comment on your behalf if one already exists).

So while the scripts are there already doing this, instead of:
"if same comment already exists: do not add comment"
Do this:
"if same comment already exists: do not add comment; upvote current comment"

Maybe it's still a fair bit of resources, with various DBs to be written too etc (?).

### Worthwhile even though temporary comment

Sure the comment is not there long, sometimes it can be but to be fair "usually" it is not.
However, this is an opportunity to educate users, and most certainly *new* users.

Having comments placed on my behalf is fine, but it's given me a few reply comments from post authors.
Such as: "@James, why should this answer be a comment, you are wrong, I have an upvote" etc.

I'm not saying if my comment had an upvote or two it would *resolve* this, but it might *ease* it, and if nothing else it's a debate point:
"The site doesn't like answers like this, blah etc, and my comment has 2 upvotes so others do agree, it's not just me being obtuse/unfair".
etc