# What exactly "duplicate comments" will be upvoted if I cast a subsequent dupe vote?

Tags: support, comments, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

**This is not a duplicate of [Autocomment when voting to close as duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate) as that simply indicates that the feature exists. This is a "how" question asking how this feature actually works, which that answer does not address.**

I just voted [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327729/350567) as a dupe, with 3 other votes existing before mine. I then noticed that I automatically upvoted the top comment, despite it not starting with *Possible duplicate of*.

> [image]

What's the exact criteria for finding *the* "duplicate comment" for automatic upvoting when I cast an extra dupe vote?

Related: [Subsequent duplicate close votes should automatically upvote the possible duplicate comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218295/350567)

Also related: When a question is closed as dupe, all comment starting with *Possible duplicate of* deletes.

Comment: As a test, try voting to close this question as a duplicate of the proposed target. Does this comment get upvoted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocomment when voting to close as duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate) - Jeff's [answer says yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44529/282094).

Comment: @Rob Not a duplicate. That question is simply the feature request and announcement of this general feature; this question is asking *about* that feature and the answer to *how* the system detects this special type of comment is not addressed in that question. This is not a simple yes-or-no question asking if comments get upvoted; this is asking *how* the system knows which comment to upvote.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog wow, really upvoted

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog The word "how" only appears on this page in your comment. You can see that you edited your 'notification comment' (as I did mine) so it seems likely that it links the comment #. An answer from a Dev will probably wait until next week.

Comment: @Rob My question asks *What's the exact criteria*, which IMO isn't quite different from *How*.

Comment: @Rob "How"-type questions need not necessarily use the word "how". Additionally, Jeff isn't saying it's implemented; just that it's a good idea (the actual feature [wasn't implemented until 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218295/subsequent-duplicate-close-votes-should-automatically-upvote-the-possible-duplic?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Comment: Between being status-completed and the discussion in the comments back and forth between the Devs I'd say they've done everything but 'give ya da codz', you're know for skimming because you're busy and have said exactly that previously; yet there's always time for multiple replies and answers. What I flagged VTCD is the oldest, the other post is newer and just regular users guessing.

Comment: @Rob As can be seen from the status tag edits on that question, that user was a Stack Exchange employee at the time, not just a regular user guessing.

Comment: Based on the OP's title alone. "What will be printed?" and "How will it be printed" are not asking for the same thing, the first is about content/text, the second question is about the mechanism behind printing. Likewise "What (*which* would be a better word here) *precise* comment will be upvoted" is not asking *how* the site's system recognises the dupe signalization comment.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "What's the exact criteria for finding it" is indeed asking how the system recognizes it.

Comment: So I would suggest that the OP modify the **title** to better reflect its meaning and intention. I specifically started my comment by saying "based on the title *alone*"

Comment: @Mari-LouA The [6th W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Ws) is for weason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an internal flag that is saved along with the comment that is automatically posted when someone votes to close as a duplicate, for a target that hasn't been selected before. When someone else votes for that same target, it makes an upvote for the comment with the internal flag indicating that it's corresponding to that specific target.

Due to the modified duplicate closing policy on this site, I often edit my "possible duplicate" comments so as to point out *how* it's a duplicate. As of January 2019, duplicate comments are [no longer automatically deleted upon closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified/321882#321882) if they were edited.